# MVC Controller Different Behavior between Form Submit and Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web

I am pretty new to MVC and web development in general so please bear with me.

In my web app, I am trying to call a controller action via an Ajax request as I only want to refresh the partial view in my page as opposed to the entire page. Everything works properly (the Partial View is returned without refreshing the main View) except the Partial View returns the wrong values. After some debugging I discovered the error was with the Request statements in the controller action. When the controller action is called by a normal form submit, the Requests are able to get the user input values, but not when I call the controller with an Ajax request; they simply return null values.

Please see the below example, it is a much much simplified version of what I am facing. When  using Ajax, the total always ends up being 0 due to the parse commands failing on a null value.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate() {
    ViewBag.Total = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {   // max number of Frames that users can add is 10
        string FrameNumber = i.ToString;
        try {
            string rawValue1 = Request["input1_Frame" + FrameNumber];
            string rawValue2 = Request["input2_Frame" + FrameNumber];
            decimal Value1 = decimal.Parse(rawValue1);
            decimal Value2 = decimal.Parse(rawValue2);
            ViewBag.Total += Value1 + Value2;
        } catch {
            break;
    }

    return PartialView("Banner");
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $("#calculate").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Calculate",
        success: function (data) {
            $(".banner").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong in the controller");
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

**View:**

```
<div class="banner"></div>
<input name="input1" type="text">
<input name="input2" type="text">
<button id="calculate">Calculate Total</button>
```

**Partial View:**

```
<div>
    Total:
    <span id="totalValue">@ViewBag.Total</span>
</div>
```

EDIT: So just to clarify as to why I don't just pass the values as Ajax parameters is because in my actual view, the number of inputs is dynamically generated with JQuery. For example, I have a frame with 15 inputs, but users may choose to add additional frames - so in total there will be 30, 45, 60,... or more inputs. I'm not exactly sure how to handle Ajax parameters that way, so for each frame I loop 15 times, increment the input ID each time, and request the data that way. I've updated the code for the controller to better visualize what I'm saying.

Comment: You better pass the parameter to controller method through ajax request rather than reading it from Request object

Comment: In your Ajax code you are not sending any post data to the server that's why you are not getting values from request.

Comment: Are your intended to submit dynamically generated fields with AJAX POST then return a partial view contains result for all submitted numbers, or returning JSON response from AJAX call as addition result without rendering partial view? Please explain in more detail.